# using flock inside crontab with node script throws an error

Tags: node.js, flock

I can't seem to execute this command from a crontab. It works fine from the command line.

## index.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

//do stuff
```

## crontab

```
*/5 * * * * flock -n /tmp/reddit.lock /usr/local/bin/node /home/user/projects/reddit/index.js -u me -p 'pass' -vvv
```

## error

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: 100% sure you're not using backticks instead of quotes somewhere? Otherwise: what happens if you add an `env -i` in front of it on the command line?

Comment: it was a special character in the password: `pass\%word` fixes it.

Comment: Ah, yes, `%` usually means a newline character in crontab... The fact it talke about line 1 instead of line 0 should have made alarm bells ringing here indeed.

Answer (score 0):

My password has a '%' in it. So I had to remove the single quotes and pass the argument as:

```
*/5 * * * * flock -n /tmp/reddit.lock /usr/local/bin/node /home/user/projects/reddit/index.js -u me -p pass\%foo -vvv
```

This took me awhile to find the problem, hopefully it helps someone else.